# Alternate Javascript file only for IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to include Js.js Normally, But when IE is used i would like Js2.js to be the Only javascript file included. How can i stop Js.js from being included when the browser is IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional statements:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="Js2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script src="Js.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `if ie` code to target IE specifically:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <script src="Js2.js">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
   <script src="Js.js">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Cf.:http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<--[IF IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // IE stuff
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also see this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx